# ways to get the path of specific file in ios

Tags: iphone, ios

To localitie items in the standard directories, I have just used either one of these:

```m
NSURL* url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"search" withExtension:@"png"]; 
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"search" ofType:@"png"];
```

The output is:

```
url  is file://localhost/Users/myName/Library/......./MyApp.app/search.png
path is                 /Users/myName/Library/......./MyApp.app/search.png
```

The difference between the two of them is the missing `file://localhost`.

My question is when should we use `URLForResource` and when we use `pathForResource`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most iOS methods offer you to use path or url, for example

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:foo]
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:foo]
```

So it doesn't really matter which one you use.

For methods that require a path you could do a conversion:

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:yourFilePath]
```

becomes

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:yourFilePath]]
```

You can also convert a URL to a Path

```
yourURL.path
```